# extracting elements of two independent arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, delegates

I'm trying to  extract each element in two double arrays i.e. `double [] X` , `double [] Y`  ,  and generate some x-y pairs (1,1) , (2,2) , (3,3) and pass them into another delegate which only takes a pair of `double x`, `double y` 
e.g I have these two arrays `X` and `Y`.
What this code basically should do is pass a pair of points to an `append` method, which then gets invoked by the delegate to plot a graph. but clicking the button to trigger the whole event.

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;


namespace LastTrial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PlotHelper plotXY = new PlotHelper();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlotHelper plotXY = new PlotHelper();
            double[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            double[] Y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            plotXY.PlotXYPass(X, Y);


        }


    }

    public class PlotHelper
    {



        private delegate int PlotXYDelegate(double x, double y);

        public void PlotXYAppend(Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double x, double y)
        {
            chart.Invoke(new PlotXYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddXY), new Object[] { x, y });
        }


        Chart someChart;
        Series someDataSeries;

        public void PlotXYPass(double[] X, double[] Y)
        {
            X.Zip(Y, (x, y) => new { x, y })
            .ToList().ForEach(
                p => PlotXYAppend(someChart, someDataSeries, p.x, p.y));
        }

    }
```

MIKE: there is still some problem, the `somechart` and `somedataseries` never get assigned.

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry I didn't make it clear enough!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method from Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

double[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
double[] Y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
Chart someChart;
Series someDataSeries;

private void PlotXYPass(double[] X, double[] Y)
{
    X.Zip(Y, (x, y) => new { x, y }).ToList()
        .ForEach(
            p => PlotXYAppend(someChart, someDataSeries, p.x, p.y)
        );
}
```

Comment: i'm really really grateful! for your help! but it still didn't work ... i think we 're very close .. see edited code

Comment: I don't know where the `Chart` and `Series` come from. The `PlotXYAppend` method from your original post required a `Chart` and a `Series`, I assumed you knew where they came from. I only put them in my example to have something to pass to the `PlotXYAppend` method.